# How to use log4j with spring batch

Tags: log4j, spring-batch

I have the following configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
        <Property name="archive">${log-path}/archive</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <File name="fileAppender" fileName="${log-path}/xmlfilelog.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I only get info logs despite I have debug function calls.

I have this maven dependency included :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something ?

In application.yml I have also added

```
logging:
 level: debug
```

Comment: I presume this is a Spring Boot application?

Comment: Yes it's a spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

For a Spring Boot application, you can configure Log4J using the starters.  The documentation for doing so can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging